# How to open URLs in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, screen-scraping

I'm trying to read in the html of a certain website.

Trying `@something = open("http://www.google.com/")` fails with the following error:

```
Errno::ENOENT in testController#show

No such file or directory - http://www.google.com/
```

Going to `http://www.google.com/`, I obviously see the site. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `require 'open-uri'` first to be able to `open()` remote paths.

See [the docs](http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you. Where would I require it? Directly in the controller?

Comment: Yeah. You can put it at the top of the file.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a utility like Nokogiri to parse the returned content like so:

(From the [Nokogiri site front page @ http://nokogiri.org/](http://nokogiri.org/))

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

# Get a Nokogiri::HTML:Document for the page we’re interested in...

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.google.com/search?q=tenderlove'))

# Do funky things with it using Nokogiri::XML::Node methods...

# Search for nodes by css
doc.css('h3.r a.l').each do |link|
  puts link.content
end
```

will print to the screen:

```
<a href="http://some.link/">Some Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually am using Nokogiri, but wanted to provide a simplified example since the problem was with `open()`, not Nokogiri itself.